# Nhibernate in c#

Tags: c#, nhibernate

i want to get data from sql server database in asp.net using NHibernate. what are the major steps i need to write for nhibernating. i have declared my class and its properties.

```
public class Student
{
    private int id;
    private string name;
    private DateTime dateofbirth;
    private string address;

    public int Id
    {
        get { return id; }
        private set { id = value; }
    }
    public string Name      
    {
        get { return name; }
        private set { name = value; }
    }
    public DateTime DateOfBirth
    {
        get { return dateofbirth; }
        private set { dateofbirth = value; }
    }
    public string Address
    {
        get { return address; }
        private set { address = value; }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to firstly make all of those properties `virtual` so that NHibernate can proxy them. Then you need to work out how to map the class to the database. You can do this with XML mapping files, or something like [Fluent NHibernate](http://fluentnhibernate.org/) - I'd recommend the latter.

And obviously you'll need a matching database - there are ways to generate a script for this using NHibernate as well if you need this. But from your question I'm assuming the database is pre-existing.

Comment: I can recommend having a look at http://www.sharparchitecture.net/ as a complete reference.